# Angular ngxs unit test dispatch doesn't work

Tags: angular, unit-testing, ngxs

I try to run unit tests for NGXS State but when I run dispatch with Action classs function it doesn't run

```
  @Action(GetProductsAction)
  loadProductPage(ctx: StateContext<ProductStateModel>, { page, size }: GetProductsAction) {
```

this is my unit test code:

```
  it('should create an action and get not empty pageProduct', () => {
spyOn(httpClient, 'get').and.returnValue(of({totalElements: 2}));
store.dispatch(new GetProductsAction(1, 20))
store.select(state => state.product.pageProduct).subscribe((pageProduct: PageProduct) => {
  console.log(pageProduct)
  expect(pageProduct.totalElements).toEqual(2);
});
const x = store.selectSnapshot(state => state.product.pageProduct);
console.log('xxx '+ JSON.stringify(x));

expect(x).toEqual({})
```

});

anyone have idea why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

`dispatch` returns an Observable that should be subscribed to or `await`ed using `toPromise` method.

You retrieve the snapshot right after dispatch, so I think the action is simply not handled.